# Updating deprecated code, from each() to foreach()

Tags: php, foreach, each, php-7.2

I'm working to fix some old code that triggers a warning on PHP 7.2.0, beacause `each()` is deprecated.

I tried to replace `each()` with `foreach()` like the following, but it doesn't work.
I found some answers on StackOverflow, but none with a straight pure `return` as in the old code I'm trying to fix.

Old code that needs to be updated (works well, but triggers a warning):

```
if ($n > 0){
    if ($n !== count($array)){
        return (bool) each($array);
    }
}
```

What I tried (and doesn't work):

```
if ($n > 0){
    if ($n !== count($array)){
        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            return (bool) $value;
        }
        unset($value);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you :)

Comment: You'd better show all the code related to this `$array`. `each` will move the internal pointer, so there may be some side effects if you use this array later.

Comment: I can give you a example.
For foreach. you need an array.
So
if ($array > 0){ foreach($array as $key => $value) { return $value; } unset($array) } now it should work. modify the array as you need. this is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the php team encourages you to manage array pointers yourself. you can replace the original array with an ArrayIterator wrapper.

```
$arrayItor = new ArrayIterator($array);
```

Then your code can be updated by using this iterator.

```
if ($n > 0){
    if ($n !== $arrayItor->count()){
        $ret = $arrayItor->current();
        $arrayItor->next();
        return (bool)$ret;
    }
}
```

---

Another approach is `current` and `next` are not deprecated yet, so you can use them to replace the `each` function

```
if ($n > 0){
    if ($n !== count($array)){
        $ret = current($array);
        next($array);
        return (bool)$ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. For some reason, the `ArrayIterator` approach doesn't work (it displays the first element n times). But the `current` and `next` approach works well, that's perfect. I hope it won't be deprecated anytime soon. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you created an ArrayIterator each time you entered this function, that's incorrect. You need create only one ArrayIterator and replace the `$array` variable with this reference.